# Creating and reading an image with metadata

Tags: clojure

I could not find anything online.
Im planning on saving Software small software data in the file.

I've had a look at [clj-exif](https://github.com/olimcc/clj-exif) and [exif-processor](https://github.com/joshuamiller/exif-processor)

but both do not seem to return what i need

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java interop to read/write any type of file. You could use [output-stream](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/output-stream)
to write any type of bytes to a file, such as the bytes of a jpeg image.

See also [the Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/04_local-io/4-11_random-access-files.asciidoc) online for more tips, and [this list of Clojure documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).